# Terminal is running on python on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python

my terminal is running on python 3.8 and I don't have the terminal when I open the terminal it opens like below:

[here is the image of terminal right after i open it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIlKS.png)

what should I do to get rid of this problem and go to normal terminal?
however I think it is because a package I installed on atom named build-python please help me.I think it is a child process but I couldn't kill it

edit : i forgot to say that when I press Ctrl+D in order to exit the python on terminal I get following screen:
[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEWAP.png)

Comment: Looks like you manipulated your environment `.bashrc` or `.profile`.

Comment: well i checked home directory and there were neither of mentioned folders! (i checked the hidden folders)

Comment: Dot files are not shown by default. Use `ls -al`. If you really don't any of theses in your folder, something is badly wrong and the problem goes beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: see the problem is that i do not have the terminal...my terminal magically runs on python...i cannot enter commands...however i checked even the hidden folders with the nautilus and i didn't see those

Comment: dear Klaus i ran below program in the so called terminal( which for me is python shell) and saw the .bashrc what can i do?>>> import os
>>> os.system("ls -al")

Comment: The question is: what did you do to get there? Installing a plugin usually does not have this result.

Comment: well i now made a virtual terminal which runs commands from from python(for temporary use) but after a little time i think that it is running a child process from another script that starts python3 but i have no idea how to fix it because i don't know which child process is doing this! take a look at edit I made!